# Round off Issue + ios

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

In my app, I have a amount field. In the amount field, the user may enter any number of digits after decimal point. But when i save it, it want to round off to 2 digits. this scenario works properly with my code. With my code, if the user enters the value 2.445, it is saved as 2.45. Likewise
 2.115 -> 2.12,
 2.125 -> 2.13,
 2.135-> 2.14,
 2.145 -> 2.15,
 2.155 -> 2.16,
 2.165 -> 2.17,
 2.175 -> 2.18 **BUT** if the user input is 2.185, in this case i need to be saved as 2.19 but it gets saved as 2.48 only. And also if input is 2.195, it should be saved as 2.20 but it gets saved as 2.19 only.. How to fix this..? I have attached my code.

```
float Rate_int = [AmountValue floatValue];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Rate_int]];
```

In short, i want to round up in all cases if the 3rd digit is greater than or equal to 5.. but 2.185 doesn't get rounded up to 2.9.. likewise 2.195 doesn't get rounded up to 2.20.. i have problem only in these two cases..

Comment: It's not very clear which cases you want to round up and which you do not

Comment: i want to round up in all cases if the 3rd digit is grater than or equal to 5.. but 2.185 doesn't get rounded up to 2.9.. likewise 2.195 doesn't get rounded up to 2.20.. i have problem only in these two cases..

Comment: Ok i understand now. The way you phrased it initially put me off

Comment: Sorry.. Now I have edited my question too.. Can u give me some fix on this..

Answer (score 3):

Use %.2f

```
NSString *strNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",2.185];
NSLog(@"%@",strNum);
```

or for up to decimal places

```
 float roundToTwo (float num)
{
    return round(100 * num) / 100;
}
```

Comment: For the input `2.195` this will output `2.19` and not `2.2`. The problem is that neither float nor double can store a number like `2.185` or `2.195` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`2.185` cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number. 
For precise decimal arithmetic, you should avoid `float` or `double`, and use
`NSDecimalNumber` instead:

```
NSString *AmountValue = @"2.185";
NSDecimalNumber *decnum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:AmountValue];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:decnum];
// gives "2.19"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a float precision issue. You can avoid this issue by using double instead of float.

```
    double Rete_int =  [AmountValue doubleValue];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

    NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:Rete_int]];
```

Comment: That is interesting. For the input `2.195`, `Rete_int = 2.19499999999999984013` because even a double cannot represent that number precisely. So I would have expected that this number is rounded *down* to `2.19`. But your code gives `2.20` ... strange.